# How can I do Cross-Origin in the google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, cross-origin-read-blocking

I tried several tutorials and nothing worked.

My problem is as follows, if I click on an html link it opens the other page, but if I try to open via form it always shows a cross-origin error.

I provide a public link with a copy of the main pages of my project. Could someone show me in practice how to solve this problem?

Project:

doGet.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(!e.parameter.page){
    //When no specific page requested and no session or the page is not to register, return Login page;
    return(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page').evaluate()
           .setTitle('Page 1')
           .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          );
  } else {
    //Use page parameter to pick an html file from the script;
    return(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate()
           .setTitle(e.parameter['title'])
           .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          );
  }
}

/*==================== That code goes include files in the page. ====================*/
function include(filename) {
  return(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
         .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
         .getContent()
        );
}

/*==================== Get the URL for the Google Apps Script running as a WebApp. ====================*/
function getScriptUrl(){
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return(url);
}
```

javaScript.html

```
<script>
/*==================== Attach a submit handler to the form. ====================*/
$("[name='loginForm']").submit(function(event){
  var $form;
  var login;
  var url;

  //Stop form from submitting normally.
  event.preventDefault();

  //Get some values from elements on the page:
  $form = $(this);
  login = {};

  login.email = $form.find("#inputUser").val();
  login.senha = $form.find("#inputPassword").val();
  url = $form.attr("action");

  var posting = $.post(url, login);

  //Post sucess.
  posting.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);

    //Redirect to page2.
    //var geting = $.get(url, login);
  });
});

/*==================== Get app url. ====================*/
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setHref)
    .getScriptUrl();
});

/*==================== Modifying link of navbar. ====================*/
function setHref(url){
  var links = $("a[href], form[action]");

  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var page;

    if(links[i].tagName == "A"){
      page = links[i].getAttributeNode("href").value;
      links[i].getAttributeNode("href").value = url + page;
    } else {
      page = links[i].getAttributeNode("action").value;
      links[i].getAttributeNode("action").value = url + page;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="loginForm" action="?page=page2&title='Page 2'" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="inputUser" name="inputUser" value=""/>
      <svg height="10" width="10">
      <path d="M4 0c-1.105 0-2 1.119-2 2.5s.895 2.5 2 2.5 2-1.119 2-2.5-.895-2.5-2-2.5zm-2.094 5c-1.07.04-1.906.92-1.906
      2v1h8v-1c0-1.08-.836-1.96-1.906-2-.54.61-1.284 1-2.094 1-.81 0-1.554-.39-2.094-1z" id="person"></path>
      </svg>
      Usuário
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" value=""/>
      <svg height="10" width="10">
      <path d="M5.5 0c-1.38 0-2.5 1.12-2.5 2.5 0 .16.033.297.063.438l-3.063 3.063v2h3v-2h2v-1l.063-.063c.14.03.277.063.438.063
      1.38 0 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5s-1.12-2.5-2.5-2.5zm.5 1c.55 0 1 .45 1 1s-.45 1-1 1-1-.45-1-1 .45-1 1-1z" id="key"></path>
      </svg>
      Senha
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <?!= include('jQuery'); ?>
    <!-- Standard JavaScript -->
    <?!= include('javaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

doPost

```
function doPost(e){
  var callback;
  var output;
  var data;

  data.e = e;
  data.url = getScriptUrl();

  //Returning the response to the application.
  callback = e.parameter.callback;
  output  = ContentService.createTextOutput();

  if (callback === undefined) {
    output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
  }

  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  return(output);
}
```

page2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <?!= include('jQuery'); ?>
    <!-- Standard JavaScript -->
    <?!= include('javaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the error, is caused when I click to submit form, in the submit function in javascript.html

> Failed to load
>   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyzqu-axemMxSmafZdEpqu1uYssWMM9SAleKzmPB_Tu-0rF8vnk/exec?page=page2&title=%27Page%202%27:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://n-iqrbuxm45ga265etahrrml6j6klncaly5mdwd3y-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Redirect page after login.
I am on the login page and after completing the form and press submit, go to page 2.

Comment: The reason for this error is because, internally, GAS web-apps are hosted on googleusercontent.com, so your app doesn't know about the published app URL. As a result, the query string is appended to the wrong URL. In your 'form' tag, change the action attribute to the following:  action="<?!=  ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + '?page=page2&title=Page 2' ?>". Note, however, that the form will still open a new tab. You also need to change the default behaviour by adding an event listener to the form. Finally, you don't seem to be using encodeUri() for the query string parameters.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include everything needed to answer your question in the question itself. Links are fine as references, but not if your question doesn't make sense without them. Thank you!

Comment: Anton Dementiev This is already done, I posted the content here to get better. Following the advice of Max Vollmer.
See that there is a function in doGet called getScriptUrl (), in JavaScript I call in the code snippet:
$ (function () {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler (setHref)
     .getScriptUrl ();
});

In the callback "setHref" is exactly as you described and even then the error does not come out, as I said, I have already followed several tutorials and nothing.

Comment: second I saw in another post, gas has no cors:
"GAS does not allow CORS headers at this time."
Why does it happen then?

Comment: It did not work, but I realized that is more used with links, I have no problems with links, only with submissions of forms.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try this and if I succeed, post the result here.

Comment: I surrender. Validate user and go to another page, even from the same project, is not possible.

Comment: @MoézioLeivas, what do you mean by this? " even then the error does not come out.." What happens when the error does not come out?

Comment: What I wanted to say was: I do as described on the reference website, but it still gets error. I think GAS is only to use as web service. What I was trying to do was to simulate the spreadsheet as a database and use the html feature to do a basic authentication, where the user only accesses the main panel if they log in.
I think it's much to GAS or it should use sending methods like XMLHttpRequest rather than simple post or get. But I do not understand anything about cors. That is my problem there.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the problem.
I try _top, _blank change post function, nothing solved.

Comment: Even if it is the problem, You don't need to redirect to page2. Just put the first form inside a `<div id ="page">`. Then onSubmit, google.script.run and get the second page as htmlBody (without html and head tags)  and `document.getElementById("page").innerHTML=page2`, where `page2` will be a htmlBody element returned by script.run. You don't even need `doPost()`. You can fake pages transition.

Comment: I was doing it like this, as you say, I just wanted to avoid it. But It seems to be the only alternative when I need authentication.
Thanks for help.